# Block list from Farm/Site Search but still allow Search against list

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-on-prem

Due to security reasons I had to disable search for certain libraries and lists from appearing in the site/farm level search box (done in advanced settings). However for  admin purposes search is still required (There are too many items to manually find one even with decent use of filters).

Is there a way to still allow lists to be searched against from the inbuilt webpart search box (or other search bars) but not from the main search bar?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a new result source and in the query builder you can exclude the paths(s) to those lists/libraries. Something like this: -Path:https://contoso.sharepoint/blog/Lists/Posts/ would exclude blog posts in that list. Then on your results page(s) you would edit the search results webpart and change it's result source to the new one you created.